# Wordpress list pages with custom field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a site with menu which list all pages which has a specific menu and load the title and a custom field image which is generated with "advanced custom fields"
I can display the title but when i try to display the image it displays the custom field image from the current page on all the menu links

Here is an example "http://appelhat.dk/bordplader/" the menu moves up when the mouse touches the buttom of the page.

Here is the code

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
        <ul>
            <?php 
                $template = 'gallery.php';
                $Pages = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND meta_value = '$template'");
                foreach($Pages as $Page) {
                    $exclude_Pages .= $Page . ',';
                }
                $pages = get_pages("include=$exclude_Pages"); 

            foreach ( $pages as $page ): 

                $title = $page->post_title
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">
                        <span class="title"><?php echo $title ?></span>
                    <?php 
                        $attachment_id = get_field('front_billede');
                        $size = "thumbnail"; 
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>   
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) rather than get_field. It sounds like get_field is calling the global $post->ID rather than the desired $page->ID.

`$attachment_id = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'front_billede', true);`

Alternatively, you can create a secondary Loop - using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to ensure all the tags are using the appropriate ID.

Answer (score 0):

In know this is a relatively old question, but if you want to use get_field in this context then you can simply use the overloaded method:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('front_billede', $page->ID);
```

Furthermore, if you want to create custom menus like this in Wordpress then I would recommend a custom Walker. Here is an example I've used previously:

```
class WP_Image_Walker extends Walker_Page {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='children list-inline'>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 )
    {
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        }
        else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

        if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);
            if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
                if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
                elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                    $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }

            $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

            $image = get_field('image_field', $page->ID);

            $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '">' . '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">';
            $output .= '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . '" />' . '</a>';

            if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
                if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                    $time = $page->post_modified;
                else
                    $time = $page->post_date;

            $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your page menu like this:

```
<?php wp_page_menu(array('walker' => new WP_Image_Walker(), 'container' => 'false', 'menu_class' => 'nav-home') ); ?>
```